# Trouble getting ngOptions to work properly in nested select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I have created an angular app which records the attributes for a product which is being created. In the page, I have 2 select dropdowns, the first one for selecting the key of the attribute and the second selects the specific value. The json data for each attribute is as follows:-

```
{
  meta_key :"Weight",
  meta_values :[
  "10","20","30","40","50"
  ],
  type : "text",
  unit:"kgs" 
}
```

Each product can have an array of attributes with the only difference being that instead of meta_values as an array, each attribute in a product will have a single value as meta_value. The JSON representation is as follows:-

```
{
  attributes : [
    {
      meta_key : "Weight",
      meta_value : "20",
      unit : "kgs"
    },
    {
      meta_key : "Volume",
      meta_value : "200",
      unit : "cm*cm*cm"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what the page looks like.

[image]

[image]

My concern is that no matter what I am trying, the second select's values which depend entirely upon the value of the first select dropdown, does not get populated.

The empty second dropdown.

[image]

I tried populating the second dropdown with static data and it works fine. But the data does not change when it depends on the selection of the first dropdown. Here is my controller.

```
    $scope.attributes = [];

    $scope.product = {
        attributes: []
    };
    $scope.current_user = {};

    var attribute = {
        meta_key: '',
        meta_values: '',
        unit: ''
    };

    AuthService.getCurrentUser(function (user) {
        $scope.current_user = user;
        $scope.product.created_by = $scope.current_user.id;
    });

    Attributes.fetchAllAttributes(function (response) {
        $scope.attributes = response.message;
        $scope.attributes.unshift({meta_key: "Select an attribute"});
        console.log("Attributes", $scope.attributes);
    });

    $scope.addAttributes = function () {
        $scope.product.attributes.push(attribute);
        console.log($scope.product);
        initDropDown($scope.product.attributes.length - 1);
    };

    $scope.initValues = function (index) {
        var selectedValue = $scope.product.attributes[index];
        console.log(selectedValue,$scope.product.attributes[index].meta_values);
    };
```

And the html partial.

```
  <div class="row attribute" ng-repeat="attribute in product.attributes track by $index">

      <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
          <select required md-select
                  ng-model="product.attributes[$index]"
                  ng-change="initValues($index);"
                  ng-options="attribute as attribute.meta_key for attribute in attributes">
          </select>
          <label>Attribute Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s12 m4" ng-show="product.attributes[$index].type == 'select'">
          <select md-select
                  ng-options="value as value for value in product.attributes[$index].meta_values"
                  ng-model="product.attributes[$index].meta_value">
          </select>
          <label>Attribute Values</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s12 m4" ng-show="product.attributes[$index].type == 'text'">
          <input type="text" id="{{$index }}" ng-model="product.attributes[$index].meta_value">
          <label for="{{$index}}">Attribute Values</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s12 m2" ng-show="product.attributes[$index].meta_key != 'Select an attribute'">
           <input id="unit" disabled ng-model="product.attributes[$index].unit">
           <label for="unit" class="active">Unit</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s12 m2">
           <a ng-click="remove($index);">
                <i class="material-icons waves-effect waves-red red-text">close</i>
           </a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I have been trying to figure it for a while now. Have tried a lot solutions. But nothing quite works. How do I solve it?  Any help will very appreciated.

Comment: Checkout this http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Xku9z/